# Expresión en Regex101.com funciona pero en código no Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, regex, unicode

Otra más sobre regex..
He creado una regex sobre un texto de un pdf formateado a través de la biblioteca [tika](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python), es decir el texto del pdf guardado en una variable, en formato unicode.

```
'^[A-Z]\S{2,} *(?:\n+ *\S+ *)*?\n*.*?\d+ +\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?%'
```

Con ella quiero conseguir:

```
Analista programador-DyD 1 49,54%

Programador-DyD 1 50,46%

TOTAL 2 100%
```

El aspecto del texto al hacer print() es este:

[image: Imagen del print(texto_pdf)]

Si mostramos el contenido de la variable sin hacer print() obtenemos esto:

[image: Imagen del texto sin usar la función print()]

Es decir, donde aparecen \n, en realidad son saltos de línea, como se aprecia en la primera imagen, en la que mostramos el contenido de la variable a través de la función print()

Cuando llevo este texto a la página web [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DSHzvd/3) el texto es capturado como yo quiero, pero al correr el script siempre me devuelve una lista vacía (utilizo el método findall del módulo re).

Tanto en este [enlace](https://regex101.com/r/DSHzvd/3) como en el de más arriba podéis ver como si que hace match. Cabe destacar que en la página de regex101.com he sustituido los \n que devuelve la variable en bruto (sin usar funcion print(), ni parseo a str, ni nada, unicode puro) por saltos de línea, para que regex101.com no trate los \n como string.

Ahora la duda. ¿Por qué en la web si funciona pero al pasar el texto en unicode no funciona?

[image: Imagen de la ejecución de la regex en consola sobre el texto unicode]

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si observas en la página web [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DSHzvd/3) la expresión regular tiene activados ciertos flags:

[image: Imagen]

En concreto tiene activas las opciones "Global" y "Multiline". La opción "Global" es irrelevante cuando usas `findall()` (aunque tiene su importancia para `match()`), pero la opción "Multiline" es fundamental, ya que con ella `^` se refiere al inicio de una línea cualquiera, pero sin ella se refiere al inicio de la cadena. Si pruebas a desactivarla verás que ya no encuentra nada.

En python estos flags se activan con parámetros adicionales de `findall`. En este caso sería:

```
ll = re.findall(r, pdf, re.MULTILINE)
```

Ahora el resultado (sobre el texto que he copiado de la página de regex101) es:

```
['Analista \nprogramador-\nDyD \n\n1 49,54%',
 'Programador-\nDyD \n\n1 50,46%',
 'TOTAL 2 100%',
 'Jefe \nproyecto 1 100%']
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia!! Otra cosa más que aprendo de ti!! 
Me apunto este dato que es importante !! Gracias de nuevo!!!!!